# Binding together dataframes from a list in purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I have a list of dataframes that all have identical numbers of columns (and rows). I want to bind them using `purrr::map_df`.

I try `map_df(my_list)` and get

`Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default`

I'm not sure what's wrong with my list. It looks good to me (each dataframe has a unique name):

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `bind_rows(my_list)`.

`map_df(.x, .f)` takes a list (the argument `.x`) and applies a function (the argument `.f`), and returns a dataframe. You've got the first argument right (probably), but you haven't supplied a function to map. If you want to use `map`, you might try `map_df(my_list, rbind)`.

Comment: Sorry, meant to write `my_list`, edited one sec after posting.

Comment: It works! Don't know why I didn't think it would work on a list like that.